# Android GridView selected item border/highlight

Tags: android, gridview, android-gallery

In the native Gallery app on Android, when `Select item` via Option Menu action, you can select multiple items, each grid item which will have a colored-border overlay on top signify as selected when clicked.

Question:

- How to do this dynamically using `getView()` in the `ImageAdapter`
  class? (since there is `setBackgroundColor()` but not setBorder()
- Is there a better way to accomplish this? (such as creating a padding
  of some sort for the image within the gridview cell, then set the
  background color which will look like a border)

Comment: And what if image url returns null or empty? Then the background of the image will corrupt your UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I finally decided to use the 2nd method in the original post: creating a padding for ImageView within the gridview cell and set the background color.
- I used `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP` with `setCropToPadding(true);` for the ImageView.

Comment: Where is the original post?